# Loop for dataset in SAS EG proc SQL

Tags: string, loops, sas, vlookup

I am new in SAS EG and I want to know how to append numbers through looping based on three column values in SAS EG.
For example.

Column0   Column1   Column2    Level (desired result)
1A        AA                     0
1A        123AA     AA           1
1A        234AA     123AA        2
2B        BB                     0
2B        123BB     BB           1
2B        234BB     BB           1
2B        345BB     123BB        2
2B        456BB     345BB        3

Would like to know if there's any way I can do a vlookup on the same table and add new column to store the result data in the same table?

Comment: Explain how you are computing level.  Is Column2 for a reference lookup in prior Column1 values of the group ?  Are levels (of a group) monotonic increasing ?

Comment: You need provide the rules for how you are restarting the counters.  The first group appears to be based on COLUMN0, but the other groups all have the same value for COLUMN0.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not know about the order of the rows as stored on disk, and your data has no additional column for values that could direct a SORTED BY.

The DATA step offers a simpler approach where the sequence of rows is 'as read'.  A hash object keyed by column1 can maintain the value of level from prior rows and column2 can be used as the key value for lookup.

For example:

```
data have;
infile datalines missover;
input
Column0 $ Column1 $ Column2 $; datalines;
1A        AA             
1A        123AA     AA   
1A        234AA     123AA
2B        BB             
2B        123BB     BB   
2B        234BB     BB   
2B        345BB     123BB
2B        456BB     345BB
run;

data want;

  set have;
  by column0;

  if _n_ = 1  then do;
    declare hash lookup();
    lookup.defineKey('column1');
    lookup.defineData('level');
    lookup.defineDone();
  end;

  if first.column0 then
    lookup.Clear();

  if (lookup.find(key:column2) ne 0) then
    level = 0;
  else
    level + 1;

  lookup.add();
run;
```

Note: The above approach may need adjustment to work in VIYA.

To do the same in SQL requires multiple steps.  One step per level being computed (or discovered) for appropriate children.

```
proc sql;
  create table level0 as
  select child.*, 0 as level from have as child
  where child.column2 is null;

  %put &=SQLOBS;

  create table level1 as
  select child.*, 1 as level from level0 as parent join have as child
  on parent.column0 = child.column0 and child.column2 = parent.column1;

  %put &=SQLOBS;

  create table level2 as
  select child.*, 2 as level from level1 as parent join have as child
  on parent.column0 = child.column0 and child.column2 = parent.column1;

  %put &=SQLOBS;

  create table level3 as
  select child.*, 3 as level from level2 as parent join have as child
  on parent.column0 = child.column0 and child.column2 = parent.column1;

  %put &=SQLOBS;

  create table level4 as
  select child.*, 4 as level from level3 as parent join have as child
  on parent.column0 = child.column0 and child.column2 = parent.column1;

  %put &=SQLOBS; * 0 obs, so no more children needing parentage found;

  create table want as
  select * from level0 union 
  select * from level1 union
  select * from level2 union
  select * from level3 
  order by column0, level
  ;
```

A generic approach would have to loop until `SQLOBS` is 0

```
  create table level&LOOPINDEX as
  select child.*, &LOOPINDEX as level 
  from level&LOOPINDEX_MINUS_1 as parent 
  join have as child
  on parent.column0 = child.column0 and child.column2 = parent.column1;
```

Comment: Why not just use all three variables in the BY statement?

Comment: I don't see a need to track `first.` or `last.` of `column1` and `column2`, and reality might not be by nor contiguous.  Presuming `column0` is the group and lookup resets for each group.  I could have keyed on `column0` and `column1` and the `.clear` would not be needed.  The trade off being doing `.clear` versus tracking past groups in the hash (memory price) once the group is passed.

Comment: Hello Richard,Column 0' is the group code and every group code there is line code which is the 'column 1' and every line code there is parent line which is the 'column 2'. If the column 2 is blank meaning it is the line code or the parent line of the group code. If the same value of column1 repeated in column 2. Meaning it is the child code of that parent line. Parent line should start from level 0 and iteratively append 1 in every level of line code which I want to show in my desired result. To know the level per column 1 as per column0 and column2. Thanks!

Comment: For future questions, clarify the question by updating the question itself.   Info added as a comment can get lost amongst other comments.  The sample code should work for you.  If you must use SQL, multiple statements (in a macro loop, or data steo loop that dosubL's) will have to be done.

Comment: Hi Richard, I only have one dataset, column0 to column2 are made by one proc sql. only missing is to identify what level is column1 based on column0 and column2 values.

Comment: Submit each create table statement by itself and you should see how the level values are being computed.  SAS SQL can't compute all the level values in one statement (the process is recursive, Note: Oracle has a special `CONNECT BY` syntax which is not present in SAS SQL)

Comment: Hi Richard, level values are not static values it depends on how many child does the group code (column 0) has. You were right lookup will reset for each group (column 0) on your previous comment. Would like to know if there's any way I can do a vlookup on the same table and add new column to store the result data in the same table?